# Using a generic as a type predicate

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Is it possible to use a generic as a type predicate in a type guard?

The following code errors:

```
type TypeValidator<T> = (input: unknown) => input is T;

const isString: TypeValidator<string> = (input) => typeof input === 'string';
```

With:

```
Type '(input: unknown) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'TypeValidator<string>'.
  Signature '(input: unknown): boolean' must be a type predicate.
```

Comment: Predicates are special — in your example case, it needs to be asserted ([example](https://tsplay.dev/NBJe4N)). If this answers your question, I can write it as an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hm, I think it's more of a type inference problem. You don't need to use `as`, just specify the return type explicitly: [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEDUCGAbAlgEycA9gJwB4YA+KAXigAo0A7MAV2AC4p6aBrGnAdxoEpypWg2BQ0AZ1gBuAFABjHDXGiJAZWB5aAc3JVhjFm049+LfSsnLNNHWVKhIOAGZi6jcmQoByK9q8yZDAg5FCQ8aBQIUQAPFl8bKAAfKBp6AFsAIwg8JKgMnBxIpBpZGTQXanF1ay1KaL4BAG8ZKChomQB6DoA9AH4ZAF8oCBRxaGbW9q6+wZkgA)